# WPF Display fake Data in designer with Collection of Interface

Tags: c#, wpf, interface, designer

I want display fake data in Visual Studio Designer. I use View Service Interface way with this aborecence (it is minimal example) :

```
-ServiceView
  -IMainWindow.cs
  -ICustomer.cs
-SampleData
  -MainWindowDesign.cs
  -CustomerDesign.cs
  -Data.xaml
```

IMainWindow.cs

```
namespace TestDesignSampleData.ServiceView
{
    interface IMainWindow
    {
        ObservableCollection<ICustomer> Customers { get; }
    }
}
```

ICustomer.cs

```
namespace TestDesignSampleData.ServiceView
{
    interface ICustomer
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

MainWindowDesign.cs

```
namespace TestDesignSampleData.SampleData
{
    class MainWindowDesign : IMainWindow
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ICustomer> Customers { get; set; }

        public MainWindowDesign()
        {
        //Customers = new ObservableCollection<ICustomer>();
        }
    }
}
```

CustomerDesign.cs

```
namespace TestDesignSampleData.SampleData
{
    class CustomerDesign : ICustomer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Data.xaml

```
<sd:MainWindowDesign xmlns:sd="clr-namespace:TestDesignSampleData.SampleData">
    <sd:MainWindowDesign.Customers>
        <sd:CustomerDesign Name="Charly Sparow"/>
        <sd:CustomerDesign Name="Jacky Chan"/>
        <sd:CustomerDesign Name="Dora Exploring"/>
    </sd:MainWindowDesign.Customers>
</sd:MainWindowDesign>
```

This can build and execute, but the data are not displayed and the designer send this error for each line of the collection in Data.xaml :

```
Error 1 The specified value cannot be assigned to the collection. 
The following type was expected: "ICustomer".
```

For some reason, Customer Design is not recognized as ICustomer.

EDIT:
I think it is Visual Studio designer bug. I dont have this problem with Blend. Maybe the Blend designer's compiler is more advanced.

Minimal Project to reproduce the error :

https://github.com/Orwel/DesignerError/releases/tag/CompiledProject

Comment: How are you using your Data.xaml content? Is there another WPF file that you want to actually use the data in?

Comment: d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=/SampleData/Data.xaml}", but problem is in Data.xaml, where Customer is not recognized as ICustomer.

Comment: Not sure, but I think Blend introduce some error in project that Visual don't know. If I create interface, design class and data in Visual, it is work and I can work with Blend to design UI.

Comment: I have again the same problem. Finaly, I replaced ObservableCollection<ICustomer> by ObservableCollection.

Comment: I suggest creating a version of your project that shows only the issue, zipping it up and uploading it somewhere so that people can look at it. I'm still not entirely sure how you are connecting everything together.

Comment: Thank for your help, I have upload a minimal project on github. [link](http://github.com/Orwel/DesignerError/releases/tag/CompiledProject)

Comment: In Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 your project (and design data) works just fine. I notice that the version of your assembly in the example is set to 1.0.0.0. If this is also the case in your real project, then this could be an issue. I've had issues with the designer + assemblies that don't change version between builds before (perhaps because the designer doesn't know the reload the assembly, because it thinks it hasn't changed?). Try changing the version to 1.0.* and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Thank, your solution work... but I don't understand. It is a bug? Why after a clean, the designer does not reload the assembly? Do you know a link explain?

Answer (score 2):

I think XAML designer has some issue with interpreting arrays/collections with interface type. If interface is not necessity, you can use inheritance instead.
Define your ICustomer -> create base class Customer that implements ICustomer and then create your special classes by inheriting Customer not ICustomer.

As you will have base class you can create array/collection of Customers instead of ICustomer which works correctly with XAML designer in Visual Studio.

Comment: Sorry, I can't test your solution. I have uninstalled VS 2013. Now, I use Visual Studio 2015 and I haven't encountered this error.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite determine if/when/how you're binding to your MainWindowDesign class, but I've had some luck in using the following structure (customised for your example) to show design time data in WPF.

```
public class MainWindowDesignFactory
{
    public static IMainWindow ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return new MainWindowDesignFactory().Create();
        }
    }

    public IMainWindow Create()
    {
        var vm = new MainWindowDesign();

        vm.Customers = new ObservableCollection<ICustomer>()
        {
            new CustomerDesign() { Name = "Charly Sparow" },
            new CustomerDesign() { Name = "Jacky Chan" },
            new CustomerDesign() { Name = "Dora Exploring" }
        };

        return vm;
    }

    private class MainWindowDesign : IMainWindow
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ICustomer> Customers { get; set; }
    }

    private class CustomerDesign : ICustomer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And then in the XAML file:

```
<Window 
    x:Class="DesignTimeDataExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:TestDesignSampleData_SampleData="clr-namespace:TestDesignSampleData.SampleData"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    Height="350" 
    Width="525"
    d:DataContext="{x:Static TestDesignSampleData_SampleData:MainWindowDesignFactory.ViewModel}">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The important elements here are the d:DataContext attribute in the XAML (which does pretty much what you expect it to, set a DataContext while you are in the designer) and the actual MainWindowDesignFactory class, which has a static ViewModel property to bind to.

There are other ways, including using:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type={x:Type TestDesignSampleData_SampleData:MainWindowDesign}, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
```

But I've had more luck with the Factory/Static property combination (the design time creation of an instance using the DesignInstance attribute is a bit wonky, using a manually created Factory gave me more control and less arcane designer errors).

The code above is a little rough but it should give you a starting point.

Comment: Thank, but it is not my problem (my english is so bad...). It is Data.xaml, who isSampleData where is error message. But when all files are in root of project, no error and data are displayed. Problem is CustomerDesign is not recognize as ICustomer, when namespace is different.